# Reorder/reshape NP array as image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, colors

I can grab the colours of an image with

```
import re
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

docName = "pal.png"
img = Image.open(docName).convert("RGB")

# Make into Numpy array
npArr = np.array(img)

# Arrange all pixels into a tall column of 3 RGB values and find unique rows (colours)
colours, counts = np.unique(npArr.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)

# Change to string
npStr = np.array2string(colours, separator = ", ")
pal = re.sub(r"\s?\[|\]\,|]]", "", npStr)
print(pal)


Using a small 4 colour sample image
```

[image: 4 colour image]
We have four colours:

51,  51,  51
179, 198,  15
255, 204,   0
255, 255, 255

Trouble is NP re-orders them in order of brightness. I want to *preserve* the order as reading it from top left to bottom right.

I need them in this order:

```
 51,  51,  51 # near black
255, 255, 255 # white
255, 204,   0 # yellow
179, 198,  15 # green
```

Can that be easily done with NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the image is, but you could use the `return_index=True` parameter in `np.unique`. This way you get the indices of the first occurrences for corresponding colours in `colours`. If you then sort these indices, you can index colours from your image to get the unique colours while preserving the order.

```
colours, idx, counts = np.unique(
    npArr.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True
)

print(npArr.reshape(-1,3)[np.sort(idx)])
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. BTW, the images are just swatches of colour. - like a mini palette - hence the order is important.